# Add Virgula in front of each word

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, text

I have a text file with more than a thousand lines, and for a certain process I need to separate the words by comma. I wanted a help to develop this algorithm in python since I'm starting in the language

**Entrada**

```
input phrase of the file to exemplify
```

**Saída**

```
input, phrase, of, the, file, to, exemplify
```

I'm trying like this:

```
import pandas as pd

 sampletxt = pd.read_csv('teste.csv' , header = None)
 output = sampletxt.replace(" ", ", ")

 print output
```

Comment: The `replace()` function, as demonstrated by all answers, is what you're looking for. However, be mindful that if you have multiple spaces between words, you might get undesired results. For example, `'a b  c'.replace(' ', ', ')` returns `'a, b, , c'`. If that's not an issue for you, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code sample you added, the question you are trying to answer is how to replace `' '` with `', '` for each row in a `pandas dataframe`.

Here's one way to do that:

```
import pandas as pd

sampletxt = pd.read_csv('teste.csv' , header = None)
output = sampletxt.replace('\s+', ', ', regex=True)
print(output)
```

**Example:**

```
In [24]: l
Out[24]: 
['input phrase of the file to exemplify',
 'input phrase of the file to exemplify 2',
 'input phrase of the file to exemplify 4']

In [25]: sampletxt = pd.DataFrame(l)

In [26]: sampletxt
Out[26]: 
                                         0
0    input phrase of the file to exemplify
1  input phrase of the file to exemplify 2
2  input phrase of the file to exemplify 4

In [27]: output = sampletxt.replace('\s+', ', ', regex=True)

In [28]: output 
Out[28]: 
                                                0
0     input, phrase, of, the, file, to, exemplify
1  input, phrase, of, the, file, to, exemplify, 2
2  input, phrase, of, the, file, to, exemplify, 4
```

---

**OLD answer**

You can also use `re.sub(..)`, as follows:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: st = "input phrase of the file to exemplify"

In [5]: re.sub(' ',', ', st)
Out[5]: 'input, phrase, of, the, file, to, exemplify'
```

---

`re.sub(...)` is faster than `str.replace(..)`

```
In [6]: timeit re.sub(' ',', ', st)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 µs per loop

In [7]: timeit st.replace(' ',', ')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 257 ns per loop
```

---

In case you have multiple spaces separating two words, the output of all the answers based on `str.replace(' ',',')` will be wrong. For instance

```
In [15]: st
Out[15]: 'input phrase of the file to  exemplify'

In [16]: re.sub(' ',', ', st)
Out[16]: 'input, phrase, of, the, file, to, , exemplify'

In [17]: st.replace(' ',', ')
Out[17]: 'input, phrase, of, the, file, to, , exemplify'
```

To fix that you need to use a regex (regular expression) that matches one or many spaces as follows:

```
In [22]: st
Out[22]: 'input phrase of the file to  exemplify'

In [23]: re.sub('\s+', ', ', st)
Out[23]: 'input, phrase, of, the, file, to, exemplify'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
the_list = entrada.split(" ") # take input & make a list of all values, separated by " "
saida = the_list.join(", ") # join all elements with ", "
```

Comment: `split()` by default splits at spaces. However, there is a difference between `split()` and `split(' ')` and the former might be more preferable.

Comment: With a few thousands line, I guess it will be a bit slow to split and join each line.. :/

Comment: I am trying to adapt to use in my text file.

Answer (score 3):

Your line is probably just a string, so you can use:

```
line.replace(" ",", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Complexity-wise you should replace the space directly with a comma, rather than traverse the phrase multiple times.

```
the_list = entrada.replace(' ', ', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to [read your input on line at a time](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/readline.html).
Then you simply use str.replace() as such:

```
sampletxt = "input phrase of the file to exemplify"
output = sampletxt.replace(" ", ", ")
```

And you're done.